# parentheses around a function

Tags: dojo

Could somebody help me understand what does this syntax mean?

Why there is a ( in front of function(), and there is a )(); after the function end?

```
(function()
{

CKEDITOR.htmlParser.cdata = function( value )
{
    this.value = value;
};

CKEDITOR.htmlParser.cdata.prototype =
{
    type : CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT,

    writeHtml : function( writer )
    {
        writer.write( this.value );
    }
};
})();
```

Could somebody please help me understand what does this syntax mean? Why there is a $ used in front of function()?

```
$ : function( rules )
{
    this._ =
    {
        elementNames : [],
        attributeNames : [],
        elements : { $length : 0 },
        attributes : { $length : 0 }
    };

    if ( rules )
        this.addRules( rules, 10 );
},
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could somebody please help me understand what does this syntax mean? Why there is a $ used in front of function()?

$ : function( rules )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next couple of parens is for executing this anonymous function. This is used basically to introduce scope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.Is this dojo or just strictly a javascript syntax?

Comment: The `$` thing looks like a part of the object, where `$` is a key and `function` is a value.